# Find index in records by recordName

Tags: indexing, swift4, record

I have `var records = [CKRecord]()`

I have `record.recordID.recordName`

How to find on which index is record.recordID.recordName in records?

I need this to update my tableView by indexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`firstIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex) method on the array.

```
let index = arr.firstIndex(where: { r in
  r.recordID.recordName == record.recordID.recordName
})
```

Notice that the index is an optional, if no element is found in the array the index will be nil.